# Form caption left aligned on Windows 10. BidiMode is RightToLeft

Tags: delphi, windows-10, vcl

On windows 10 the form title caption is aligned to the left even though it's BiDiMode=bdRightToLeft.
On Windows 7 the caption is right aligned as needed.
This is a VCL program. I tried both Delphi 7 and Delphi XE5.
How can i solve this problem? Is it fixed in recent version of Delphi?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What locale is your machine? Is it an RTL locale?

Comment: Current system locale in Windows 10 computer is Hebrew (Israel)

Comment: Does the version resource specify hebrew?

Comment: Yes. Local ID: $040D Hebrew (Israel)

Comment: Additionally the shell language have to be hebrew, see CreateWindowEx.

Comment: I tried Params.ExStyle := Params.ExStyle or WS_EX_LAYOUTRTL 
in the form's CreateParams. The caption was aligned to the right 
but then the form controls where left aligned.
Perhaps there is a conflict with the BidiMode property ?

Answer (score 1):

I think Windows 10 shows the title as configured on the system.
That is, if you install Hebrew or Arabic, the title will move to the right.